# finding number of parent elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a small project I need to find out the number of same divs for the parent of a clicked button. So I have a structure similar to this

```js
$(document).on("click", '.countthem', function() {
  let n = $(this).parent(".bar").length;
  $(".number").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number"></span>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><button class="countthem">should give 3</button></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><button class="countthem">should give 2</button></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Which obviously does not work. I would need the number of `.bar`in the actual `.foo`but have no idea how to access them.

Comment: `$('.bar', $(this).closest('.foo')).length` Gets length of all `.bar` collection of items inside current ancestor with class `.foo`. That's what you want, right?

Comment: Torf, you say *find out the number of similar divs for the parent*. Does this mean the class name of the parent is dynamic and you want to count all siblings of parent with same classes as parent? I'm asking if `.bar` is known or could be anything, depending on what was clicked.

Comment: Sorry. I should have explained more clearly. The classname `.bar` is given, but the page is highly dynamic. I do not know how many `.bar`are in each `.foo`and also the number is sometimes changing. So I need to know the amount of `.bar`in `.foo`at the time the user hits the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo 1 - by Class

- Register the button for the `click` event
- Then from the button find the `closest()` `.foo`
- Then from `.foo` `find()` all of its `.bars`

### Demo 2 - by Tag

- Register on `<button>`
- Then from `<button>` find its `parent()`
- Then find the parent's `siblings()` and count them and don't forget the parent +1

### Demo 3 - Plain JavaScript

**Details are in demo**

---

### Demo 1 - by Class

```js
// Register the button for click event 
$('.countthem').on("click", function() {

  /* From the button use .closest() to find the
  || closest element with the class .foo
  */
  var foo = $(this).closest('.foo');

  /* Now find() .foo's descendants that have
  || the class .bar and get the quantity with
  || the .length property
  */
  var val = foo.find('.bar').length;

  /* Finally find the .number and display the number
  || of .bars that .foo has
  */
  $('.number').text(val);
});
```

```css
output,
button {
  font: inherit
}

.number::before {
  content: 'There are ';
}

.number::after {
  content: ' .bars';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<output class="number"></output>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Demo 2 - by Tag

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {

  var qty = $(this).parent().siblings().length + 1;

  $('output').text(qty);
});
```

```css
output,
button {
  font: inherit
}

.number::before {
  content: 'There are ';
}

.number::after {
  content: ' .bars';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<output class="number"></output>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Demo 3 - Plain JavaScript

```js
// Register the body to the click event
document.body.addEventListener('click', countBars, false);

function countBars(e) {

  /* if the clicked element (e.target) is NOT
  || the element registered to event (body and
  || now referred to as e.currentTarget as well)
  || then...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    // Get the closest() .foo
    var foo = e.target.closest('.foo');

    // Find all .bars under .foo then their quantity
    var qty = foo.querySelectorAll('.bar').length;

    // Set .number value to that number
    document.querySelector('.number').value = qty;
  }

}
```

```css
output,
button {
  font: inherit
}

.number::before {
  content: 'There are ';
}

.number::after {
  content: ' .bars';
}
```

```html
<output class="number"></output>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <button class="countthem">should give 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you want both the parent and it's same class siblings count:)

```js
$(document).on("click", '.countthem', function() {
  let selector =  $(this).parent().attr('class').split(" " ).map((e)=>"." + e).join( " " );
  let n = $(this).parent( selector).siblings(selector).length + 1;
  $(".number").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number"></span>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="foo bar"><button class="countthem">should give 3</button></div>
  <div class="foo bar"></div>
  <div class="foo bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><button class="countthem">should give 2</button></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `selector = '.' + $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ').join('.')`. Will also work when parent has more than one class. It will still fail miserably when parent has no class at all, but it's better than what you have, which only works when parent has one class.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this . access the top parent of all `.bar` `divs` and then count them descendant.

```js
$(document).on("click", '.countthem', function() {
  let n = $(this).parents(".foo").children('.bar').length;
  $(".number").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number"></span>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><button class="countthem">should give 3</button></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><button class="countthem">should give 2</button></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to select grandparent element and search inside your `.bar` elements

```
$(document).on("click", '.countthem', function() {
  var n = $(this).parent().parent().find('.bar').length;
  $(".number").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
});
```